# How to use JWT token in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm currently learning .NET programming. I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project.

Here is my API login code returning an `accessToken`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserLoginRequest model)
{
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]);
    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

    IdentityOptions _options = new IdentityOptions();

    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                 new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
                    new Claim("Id", user.Id),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, user.UserName),
            new Claim(_options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType, user.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(_options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType, user.UserName)
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
            Issuer = _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
            Audience = _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };

    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    var accessToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

    return Ok(new { AccessToken = accessToken });
}
```

Here is my setup in `program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContextConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure()));
var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
    ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
};
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(o =>
    {
        o.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
    });

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("EmployeeOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("EmployeeNumber"));
    options.AddPolicy(Constants.Policies.RequireAdmin, policy => policy.RequireRole(Constants.Roles.Administrator));
    options.AddPolicy(Constants.Policies.RequireManager, policy => policy.RequireRole(Constants.Roles.Manager));
});

AddScoped();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

When I make an API call with that `accessToken` in the header, it always returns the login page.

Here is my call:

[image: Here is my call]

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: "When I make an API call with that accessToken in the header," How do you make the API call  with that accessToken in the header ? Could you share it ? So that we can reproduce the problem .

Comment: i've edit post sir

Comment: Are your api call  for the GetItem and login action both in the same project ?

Comment: Yes. It is the same project

Comment: Do you add `app.UseAuthentication();` before 
`app.UseAuthorization();` in the Program.cs ?

Comment: I already did that in my project.

Comment: Strange. I test your code and I can excute the  action with `[Authorize]` attribute. Do you have other configuration for the login  in program.cs?   Could you share full code of the program.cs ?

Comment: sure. I already edited in my post

Comment: When i loged in with login action in postman. I can use with inherit auth from parent. And it work perfectly. But i want to use this api in flutter so i want to use jwt token

Comment: What's the attibute with your GetItem action  ? I set the Jwt configuration like yours without the AddAuthorization policy and use jwt token fine. You can try to use a method  only with `[Authorize]` attribute to have a try.

Comment: I only use [Authorize]. I want to get name of user from User.Identity.Name too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use "Bearer" scheme by add `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes=JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` before the action that you want to use  JWT token .

like:

```
 [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
 public IActionResult Privacy()
 {
     var name = User.Identity.Name;
     return View();
 }
```

result:

[image]

You can look [Selecting the scheme with the Authorize attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-7.0#selecting-the-scheme-with-the-authorize-attribute) to know more.